# How to simplify if statement into loop

Tags: php, loops, if-statement

I'm currently doing this if statement here, I wanted to simplify it into a loop. I try putting it into an array for the client_fullname and etc. but turns out only string form can be done. I wanted to simplicity this coding into a loop but i have no idea how to do it.

```
<tr class="sale" data-id="<?= $sale['id']; ?>">
                    <td><?= $pagination->offset + $key + 1; ?></td>

                    <?php if ($checked_columns['client_fullname']): ?>
                    <td><?= $sale['client_fullname']; ?></td>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php if ($checked_columns['client_email']): ?>
                    <td> <a href="admin/sales" class="style1"><?php echo $sale['client_email']; ?></a></td>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php if ($checked_columns['client_phone_number']): ?>
                    <td> <a href="admin/sales" class="style1"><?php echo $sale['client_phone_number']; ?></a></td>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php if ($checked_columns['total_amount']): ?>
                    <td><?= $sale['total_amount']; ?></td>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php if ($checked_columns['total_sales_amount']): ?>
                    <td><?= $sale['total_sales_amount']; ?></td>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php if ($checked_columns['first_date_buy']): ?>
                    <td><?= $sale['first_date_buy']; ?></td>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php if ($checked_columns['created_at']): ?>
                    <td><?= $sale['created_at']; ?></td>
                    <?php endif ?>

                </tr>
```

Comment: If there isn't a value - do you still need the `<td>` tags to make the columns line up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference the below example to achieve your desired output.

```
<?php 
foreach($checked_columns as $key=>$column){
    if ($column){
    if ($key == 'client_email' || $key == 'client_phone_number'){?>
    <td> <a href="admin/sales" class="style1"><?= $sale[$key]; ?></a></td>
    <?php }else{?>
    <td><?= $sale[$key]; ?></td><?php
    }
}
```

Comment: You need a new opening `<?php` tag after the `</td>`. It's probably simplest to just keep it all in PHP and `echo "<td>{$sale[$key]}</td>";`

Comment: @Nick, Corrected thnx :)

Comment: This would not properly account for `client_email` and `client_phone_number`, as these have additional html with them.

Comment: @Qirel, Yes I know that but that will require hard-coding but the question is about looping of those elements.

Comment: Ahhhh yeah @Qirel is correct about that. I totally forgot that client_email and client_phone_number have additional html codes. so doing your coding just now with ignore the html codes. I still want it to loop without removing the html codes for 2 columns

Comment: Thanks @Rohit.007 that codes meet with my requirements.

Comment: If this answered your question, consider accepting it - thereby marking it as the correct answer.

Comment: Yes its the closest to what I'm currently doing. Got to adjust it a bit. but still. this is the correct answer

Comment: Will do, commended